# Android foreground service amount limits

Tags: android, memory-management, android-service, limit, foreground-service

I am currently working on an application designed for runners. Functionality of my app depends on 3 services: Bluetooth, Gps, Training. Bluetooth and Gps starts with an app and goes foreground together with foreground training service.
My question:

Is there a limit here regarding how many such services I can add? Will having more services that can work also in foreground make my application too resource consuming? As far as i know the most popular apps use only one service to manage tasks which i mentioned.

Comment: I can't find documentation for the number of services, you can run simultaneously. You will have to check it out yourself. Is there an actual need for three services though?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no practical limit on the number of services you can have, and each additional `Service` class, in and of itself, probably takes about the same resources as a POJO. The features you _add_ to that `Service`, however -- that may be a different story. But it rarely makes sense to have more than one `Service`, b/c all a `Service` really is is a flag to indicate to the system, "hey, I'd like my app to keep running in the background". You could've put your BT/GPS/training logic anywhere you want; Android doesn't know/care which `Service` it's a "part" of.

Comment: @GiorgosNeokleous I need Bluetooth and Gps to work after app starts, while the Training Service only when user trigger "Start Training" button. So i asume it is the best method to save resources to not use training components when it is not needed.

Comment: @greeble31 Doesn't putting all stuff in one service break the single responsibility rule?

Comment: @Swierszczu consider that you can put the logic in 3 separate modules (classes), which are not `Service` subclasses. Then your `Service` logic would go in a 4th module.

Comment: @greeble31 Perhaps you are right, but it's a pity that I couldn't find documentation showing that running more services is a mistake. Then we could finally assess which method is the correct one. Besides, thank you for the answer.

Comment: @Swierszczu As far as I'm aware, no such documentation exists.